# Checking for resource changes with HTTP ETag

Tags: php, etag

My mobile application queries a PHP API to grab data from server and display it on mobile.

My aim is to check whether the resource on the server has been changed. If yes, take it to update my cached version of data. Else, use my current version since it's the most recent one.

For that purpose, I am intending to use HTTP ETag, but I am confused about the right ETag I should use on my PHP API script.

The PHP API return is JSON:

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/json' );
echo '{"Product List":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
```

What relevant `ETag` should I add?

Is my approach right to proceed?

Comment: Actually, I decided to get rid of that approach for my case. Instead, I found a more performant way (server time + processing client time) which consist on downloading the whole data (each time the app launch or become active-return foreground) and saving it to coredata. Around 15000 instances are getting saved in around 2 seconds. So that was simpler to me. Of course this is not an answer to the HTTP ETag question. (the most important thing is to get your PHP Api refactored and optimized in a way to return the JSON response very quickly)